# Python barplot x-axis issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm fairly newish to Python in general and I'm undertaking a project but I've hit a bit of a roadblock and need a fresh pair of eyes to look over it.

Essentially, I am trying to group together a column called 'Description', then sum up all the quantities of that column and sort by largest to smallest. I then want to visualise this in a barplot. I've got as far as having the bar plot generate, the problem is that the x-axis is showing the wrong products description. I'll link some images of exactly what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLnSQ.jpg.

Here is the code I'm working with also:

```
 product_group = olS.groupby('Description')
    product_group.sum().sort_values(by='Quantity', ascending = False)

    quantity_ordered = product_group.sum()['Quantity'].sort_values(ascending = False)

products = [product for product, products in product_group]

    plt.bar(products, quantity_ordered)
    plt.ylabel('Quantity Ordered')
    plt.xlabel('Description')
    
    plt.xticks(products, rotation='vertical', size=10)
    plt.xlim(0,10)
    plt.show()
```

appreciate any support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own dataset with only two columns "Quantity" and "Description":

```
df1 = df.groupby('Description').sum(['Quantity']).sort_values(by='Quantity',ascending = False)
plt.bar(df1.index, df1['Quantity'])
plt.ylabel('Quantity Ordered')
plt.xlabel('Description')
    
plt.xticks(df1.index, rotation='vertical', size=10)
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.show()
```

Another option is to reset the index like this:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Description').sum(['Quantity']).sort_values(by='Quantity',ascending = False).reset_index()
```

and replace `df1.index` with `df1['Description']`.

Comment: amazing THANK YOU so much!! I'm still trying to understand where I went wrong, but this is a massive help, thanks again.

Comment: After grouping, the description column became the index, if you want to get the names of groups (descriptions), you can only print the index of the data frame. Another option is to reset the index after grouping and that makes a description as a column instead of an index and you will be able to call the description column.